# Create bootable and writeable Fedora USB-Stick

Tags: fedora, usb-drive, bootable, usb-device

I'm trying to create a bootable and writeable USB-stick with Fedora 30, because on the one side I want to be able to add and modify a Kickstart-File and on the other side I want to install additional software during the automatic installation process (e.g. Dell Command Configure) which I have to copy to the stick.

Because my knowladge regarding partioning is quite limited, the original Fedora 30 Stick (created with `dd bs=4M if=Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-30-1.2.iso of=/dev/sda`) is a bit strange for me:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 57.3 GiB, 61505273856 bytes, 120127488 sectors
Disk model: Ultra
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x34258370

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        0 3778815 3778816  1.8G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2         172   20119   19948  9.8M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda3       20120   62103   41984 20.5M  0 Empty
```

Why are those partitions created as type "Empty" and why are the partitions overlapping?

```
Command (m for help): v
Partition 1: overlaps partition 2.
Partition 1: overlaps partition 3.
Remaining 116348670 unallocated 512-byte sectors.
```

I read about that this is the case with extended/logical-partitions, but that seems not to be the case here.

The filesystems of the stick:

```
$ df -T /dev/sda*
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs       devtmpfs   1911628       0   1911628   0% /dev
/dev/sda1      iso9660    1889408 1889408         0 100% /tmp/1
/dev/sda2      vfat          9936    9464       472  96% /tmp/2
/dev/sda3      hfsplus      20992   12040      8952  58% /tmp/3
```

Those overlapping partitions are the main point, why I was not able to "reverse engineer" the stick 1:1. A test with non-overlapping partitions, vfat and rsyncing the files to the stick resultet in that it booted but I got the following output and that's it.

```
error: ../../grub-core/fs/fshelp.c:254:file '/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz' not found
error: ../../grub-core/loader/i386/efi/linux.c:206:you need to load the kernel first.
```

How can I build a working bootable and writeable Fedroa-Stick?

Comment: 1. I know a tool that works with Debian and Ubuntu: [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can make a persistent live drive; 2. An alternative might be to create an [installed system in the USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) (installed like into an internal drive, but in this case in a USB drive, and it should definitely work with Fedora).

Comment: I think the cloned drive (by `dd`) contains the ElTorito boot structure, probably modified with `isohybrid` to be bootable both via a DVD disk and a USB pendrive. And I think there is an iso 9660 file system which is read-only. You can see more details with `lsblk -f`, maybe run as `root`. (Let us hope someone has made a tutorial or shellscript to make a persisstent live drive for Fedora, but I don't know of it.)

Comment: Someone *has* made a tutorial and shellscript to make a persisstent live drive for Fedora. See [**this link**](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/index.html). Scroll down to **Using the livecd-iso-to-disk tool**.